# MySQL query for getting all foreign keys and the sum of all their columns in m:n table

Tags: mysql

I have got a mySql table where employees and their work hours on a specific day are stored in. I tried to write a query where i get all `employee_id`'s with their sum of hours of work in a calendar week and I don't have another idea how to do it.

This is what it should look like:

employee_id | hours(sum)
1           | 21.5
2           | 28
3           | 3

I tried it with this statement:

`select employee_id, sum(hours) from xxx.hours_of_work where week(date_of_work)=weekofyear('<date_inside_one_calendar_week>')`

But it only returns:

employee_id | hours(sum)
1           | 52.5

**Table**
[image: 1]]

**Entries**
[image: 2]]

Comment: Some observations: you appear to have a valid natural key on (employee_id,date_of_work) meaning the surrogate is redundant. And Hours is far more likely to be DECIMAL.

Comment: Which of the columns should be able to replace the surrogate? No entry here is unique exept for idhours_of_work or what do you mean? I will switch to decimal in the next revision of my DB. Does decimal have more benefits ober Double?

Comment: I think my comment is fairly clear !?!?

Comment: Ah I re read your comment and now I get it. Sorry for this. Ok than it is clear to me. And I just have to treat (employee_id, date_of_work) the same as i treated idhours_of_work till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY` to do aggregation :

```
SELECT employee_id, sum(hours) 
FROM xxx.hours_of_work 
WHERE week(date_of_work) = weekofyear('<date_inside_one_calendar_week'>)
GROUP BY employee_id
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine.   Why do you mean my statement might have errors?

Comment: @moessi774 `'<date_inside_one_calendar_week` is not like a column. ;-D

Comment: Yes, it should be a date. But i placed a spacer in the brackets. Forgot the closing `>` though. Thank you for your fast answer. Will accept answer your answer after cooldown.